# How to define a majority function in a communication game?

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory

Suppose that we have a communication game of $N$ players. Every player $i$ receives a tuple of $N-1$ messages that is a recommended strategy of the other player $j$. I define the recommended strategies that a player receives as $r_i=(g_j)_{j\in N-\{i\}}$. I want to define a map that is called majority functions such that it will take as input the recommend strategies and give back a proportion, that is a number in $[0,1]$. If $maj>1/2$ then player O will choose the recommend strategy as her strategy. How do I define the majority function?

Comment: Shouldn't your function specify a proportion for each possible strategy that could be suggested?

Comment: Yes you are right...